# Using the Inverse Function Theorem for complex functions

Tags: complex-analysis, analytic-functions

Let $A\subseteq\mathbb{C}$ be a region in the complex plane.

Let $f:A\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$ be an analytic function on $A$ and $f\left(A\right)\subseteq\left\{z\in\mathbb{C}:|z|=3 \right\}$.

Show that f is a constant function.

I'm having a bad while with this problem. The first thing I tried was to get 
$f'(z)=0, \forall z\in A$ so the function would be a constant, but I failed to get it.

The second idea I have is to try to get $f'(z)\neq0$ so I can aply the Inverse Function Theorem. I'm not getting into this problem.

Any ideas?
Thanks in advanced.

Comment: Your second idea works. Where do you see the difficulty?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't know the open mapping theorem, write $f=u+iv$ where $u$ and $v$ are real-valued. Then by assumpton, $u^2+v^2=9$. Differentiate and use Cauchy-Riemann's equations to show that all four derivatives $u'_x$, $u'_y$, $v'_x$ and $v'_y$ must be identically $0$.